# Changing datetime index to seconds

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

I am attempting use the [Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/saturating_forecasts.html#forecasting-growth) forecasting package but my data is better indexed on seconds than in days.  It does not seem that the primary argument in forecasting function takes non-integer values. Therefore, I am trying to index the dates in my dataframe by seconds. For some reason, I am not having success.

Here is a screengrab of the dataframe:
[image: screengrab of original df]

Not really relevant to the question, but I do remove some columns in between the initial and secondary screengrabs.

However, when I run

```
df_test.set_index("date", inplace=True)
df_test.asfreq("S")
```

I get the following result
[image: screengrab of nan-filled df]

I am unsure of why I am now getting `NaN` values after I reset the index. **If you know why, please let me know how to fix this.**

Comment: Brief update: with `df_test.index = df_test.index.round("S")` I can round the initial index of the dataframe to the nearest second. However, when I run `df_test.asfreq("S")`, I only get values every three seconds. Would still like to have values every second if possible using the index.

Comment: you could resample to 1s (or use asfreq, e.g. shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607986/add-missing-timestamp-row-to-a-dataframe/65608609#65608609)) and then floor to seconds. but keep in mind that the underlying data that you see in a datetime Series actually *is* 64bit signed int, counting nanoseconds since 1970-01-01

Comment: @MrFuppes got it.  I think I figured out that rounding the index to seconds was good enough for `Prophet` to work with. So my overall problem is resolved even though my question here on SO is partially resolved. Thanks